# Cannot pick a random search result using Selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

As a novice to selenium, I am trying to automate a shopping site on selenium webdriver with java, My scenario is that when i search with a keyword and get results, i should be able to pick any one of the results randomly, but I am unable to pick the random search result, either I am getting a "No such element" or when i try to click the same result everytime,search results seem to vary from time to time. please help on how to proceed further.

here is the code :

```
package newPackage;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
public class flipKart {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver dr = new ChromeDriver();
dr.get("http://m.barnesandnoble.com/");
dr.manage().window().maximize();
dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='search_icon']")).click();
dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
[@id='sk_mobContentSearchInput']")).sendKeys("Golden Book");
dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
[@id='sk_mobContentSearchInput']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='skMob_productDetails_prd9780735217034']/div/div")).click();                       
dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pdpAddtoBagBtn']")).click();
}
}
```

Comment: Can u provide html code of results

Comment: Provide the url of the website

Comment: http://m.barnesandnoble.com/

Comment: sry, i cannot copy the html code here

Comment: read this and then modify your questionm if you want others to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: If you can't post the actual HTML then you will need to sanitize the HTML and post it. We can't help you if you don't provide the basic information that we need to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should write any method that would try to wait for the visibility of the element that needs to be clicked.

You could use driver.sleep() to check.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer with your info, but these tips may help:

1. If you're getting no such element, try to verify the css selector or xpath you are using is correct.  Firefox's Firebug Firefinder is an excellent tool for this.  It will highlight the element your selector points to.
2. If your selector is correct, make sure you are using findElementsBy... and not findElementBy...
   the plural version will return a list of webelements, from which you can then pull random elements to click on.
3. Use an intelligent wait to make sure the elements have loaded on the page.  Sometimes selenium will try to interact with elements on the page before they appear.  The selenium api has plenty of methods to help here, but if you're just debugging a quick Thread.sleep(5) when you load the page will work.